# User login architecture for Android client and Grails RESTful services

Tags: android, rest, authentication, grails

Unfortunately I haven't any tried and tested code for this, simply because I think there may be various ways to do this, but I am simply looking advice on which is best, as security and authentication is not my strong point.

I wish to have initially 2 clients - an android app and a grails based web client, both hitting grails RESTful web services.  I have REST resources currently returning some data from the domain when using the web client, next step is to get the same data back into the android app.  At the same time I want to integrate some user authentication so that the user must be logged in in order to receive back this JSON data from the REST layer.

In the past I have used Apache Shiro when creating a grails app when only using the grails web  based client, is it possible to do the same with an android ap as the client?

Comment: Just to mention, you have to implement the login (and the session management) on the client side if you don't want your application to violate the [stateless constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) of REST.

Answer (score 0):

In my Grails project with web/android front-ends I'm using for android auth a slightly extended version of `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME` token (yes, I'm using `spring-security-core`++ plugin). This fits well in the application, is an easy to implement, tried and tested solution.

Comment: shiro should be able to work the same then?  Are you managing the auth in the backend and just passing a token or something to the various clients?

Comment: the clients are generating and hashing the tokens on their own, and the back-end is aware of that. I'm not using `user-sessions`, the token is simple sent along each request. I have never used shiro, but I can't imagine a reason, why something similar would not work there..